Asking for Bluetooth Permissions on MacOS
I'm currently developing a desktop application using Electron and the Noble Node.js module for BLE connections. I'm also using Electron Forge with Webpack, TypeScript, and React.
When I run the Electron application on the dev server (via npm start in the terminal), everything works as intended. If I then package the application for MacOS and open the app, the Bluetooth adapter state is reported as "unauthorized." This implies that the application doesn't have access to the Bluetooth adapter, which makes sense, as MacOS never asked if I wanted to grant Bluetooth permissions to the app.
The weird part is that if I open the application's contents and run the executable directly (right click on the app > Show Package Contents > Contents > MacOS > run the executable directly), it prompts for Bluetooth permissions. If I accept, everything works as expected again, just as it does on the dev server.
Why is this the case? Is there any way to request Bluetooth permissions through Node.js/Electron? I found node-mac-permissions, which has the ability to check for Bluetooth permissions, but not to request Bluetooth permissions. I also found systemPreferences, built into Electron, but there's nothing Bluetooth related as far as I can tell.
Edit: it seems as though the reason the dev server and running the executable directly work is because VS Code/Terminal are able to ask for Bluetooth permissions:

If I give the application Bluetooth permissions manually (by selecting the "+" in the above image, and then navigating to the packaged application), everything works as intended.
Is there any way my application can prompt the user for Bluetooth permissions?
